# jmeter: How to set the thread count for the existing jmx file in java code?

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to parameterize the thread count in the java code for the `jmx` file which is envoked.

Please tell me how to do it?

My basic aim is to start with thread count of 10 and then increase it by 10 folds in the java code using loops.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define number of threads in .jmx file using JMeter Property via [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function like `${__P(threads,)}`

[image: JMeter Properties]

2. Depending on how you launch JMeter you can set the property value like:

   - for command line: `jmeter -Jthreads=10`
   - via *user.properties* file - add `threads=10` line to it
   - programmatically via [JMeterUtils](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) class

     ```
     JMeterUtils.setProperty("threads", "10");
     ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for comprehensive information on JMeter Properties and ways of working with them.

Comment: but JMeterUtils.setProperty("threads", "10");  approach not working for me, can you please share some sample code with passing threads, ramup, parameters

Comment: but JMeterUtils.setProperty("threads", "10");  approach not working for me, can you please share some sample code with passing threads, ramup, parameters. the following is my code     JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("C:/Users/Public/softwares/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:/Users/Public/softwares/apache-jmeter-5.0"); JMeterUtils.setProperty("users", "50");  File in = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\WebTours.jmx"); HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
        in.exists();  jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    
        jmeter.run();